# Form action not working like I think it should

Tags: php

I have a form action like this:

```
<form id="comment" name="comment" action="delivery_add_comment_submit.php?jobno=<?php $jobno?>">
```

but when I go to the page the url is this:

```
http://10.10.0.2/portal2/delivery_add_comment_submit.php?txtCommentor=bhunt&txtComment=lkn%3Bk&submit=Add+Comment
```

I am switching from ASP to PHP so not sure if there is something different I need to be aware of. Is PHP automatically adding the form information to the URL? Can I not add ?jobno=" to the end of an action?

Comment: `<form method="POST">`?

Comment: could you post the form contents?

Comment: in this case there is no different between asp or php. they all use html for forms ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not defining a method in your form, it defaults to GET.

Update the form to

```
<form id="comment" name="comment" action="delivery_add_comment_submit.php?jobno=<?php $jobno?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks. I kinda just figured that out. I used the POST method.